# How to align rotated text and icons in CSS

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, sidebar

I am trying to teach myself CSS and I am struggling with alignment. What I want to achieve is to have a fixed sidebar that has some icons and a rotated text, all of them should be in a column.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="Sidebar">
    <div id="S1" class="SBlock">
        <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="Twitter_Logo.png" width=10px height=10px></a>
    </div>
    <div id="S2" class="SBlock">
        <a href="https://linkedin.com"><img src="Linkedin_Logo.png" width=10px height=10px></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Follow" class="SBlock">
        Follow Us
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}

#S1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
}

#S2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
}

#Follow {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Which produces this:

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXaVW.jpg)

It works fine for the icons, I assume that is because they are the same size, but the text is way further to the right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .Sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .SBlock {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    #Follow {
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      white-space: nowrap;
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
      text-orientation: mixed;
    }
```

Try this...

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution produced something funny looking, the text now goes off screen to the left and the icons are gone. Not sure how to add an image in the comment, otherwise I would show you.

Comment: Update: I got the icons back, that was a stupid mistake on my part, but the text is still not being rotated by -90 degrees any more.

Comment: And I solved it, since I now understood the "writing-mode: vertical-rl;", I had to change the rotation to 180deg obviously... Sorry for being so slow and thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `writing-mode: sideways-lr` instead of `transform: rotate(-90deg)` to avoid the extra space. And you don't need `position: absolute` to get all items align in the sidebar.

Read more about [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).

```css
.Sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
}

#Follow {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  color: blue;
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="Sidebar">
    <div id="S1" class="SBlock">
        <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="Twitter_Logo.png" width=10px height=10px></a>
    </div>
    <div id="S2" class="SBlock">
        <a href="https://linkedin.com"><img src="Linkedin_Logo.png" width=10px height=10px></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Follow" class="SBlock">
        Follow Us
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and especially the link, I now understand the writing-mode property!

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you use Flexbox which is so nice for designing layouts also, alignment is so easy using it.
This article is a good point to start:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for the link, this was very helpful and I feel like I got a grasp on how that works now. For some reason I still can't solve my problem though. It seems to me that the solution provided by Sampath Bandara should work, after reading through the article I only added a justify-content: space-evenly; to it to distribute it vertically, but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: Problem solved, I was just being a dummy. Thanks for the link again!